# How to differentiate JSONArray and JSONObject from InputStream using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my app I get JSON content as InputStream. Depending if its a single JSONObject or a JSONArray of those I want to perform different actions.

How can I differentiate, using Jackson, if it is an single object or an array of objects?

// cheers

SOLUTION:

Using JsonNote.isArray():

```
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(contentStream, JsonNode.class);    
List<Map<String, Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    if(rootNode.isArray()){
        // do something with the array

    } else {
        // do something else with the object
    }
```

Comment: Can you post how the data is formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind as either `java.lang.Object` (and see if you got a `List` or `Map`); or as `JsonNode` and call `isObject()` or `isArray()` on it?